# How to visit UIApplication object in background thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my dispatched background thread , I need do something like this :

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == dark)
{
    // do something
}
else 
{
    //do something else 
}
```

but the main thread checker will warn about this

```
"-[UIApplication keyWindow] must be used from main thread only"
```

And i don't think i can dispatch the visit to main thread can work in my situation , so how to visit traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle in background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put a copy of this data where the background thread can access it. I would also monitor the trait collection on the main thread so I could dispatch to the background thread when it changes. That way the background thread can rerun this code at that time.